# set title in terminal

Tags: terminal, opensuse, xfce

I`m using opensuse (xfce environment)
openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11.4
CODENAME = Celadon

unfortunately whenever I am using more than one terminal (using Tab option), It starts to ask me ¨set a title¨ which is really annoying.
Even when I set a title for each of them, when I switch between terminals , It aks same question again.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: terminal Emulator!